# How to write a Celery task using postmarker

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery, django-celery, postmark

I am trying to write a celery task which uses the [postmarker client library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/postmarker) to send emails. This is a simple client library that calls the postmarkapp.com API endpoint.

```
# In tasks.py

@app.task(bind=True)
def send_email(...):
    """Sends a single email via Postmark."""
    postmark = PostmarkClient(...)
    response = postmark.emails.send(...)
    log.info('Postmark API send_email response %s', response)
```

But when I attempt to execute the task in my tests:

```
# in test_tasks.py

class PostmarkSendEmail(TestCase):
    def test_call_send_email(self):
        send_email(...)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: <@task: tasks.send_email of groot at 0x7f2c35b9e911> is not JSON serializable
```

My question is this, is it possible to use this client library within a celery task? is there something I can do to enable me to use this library in a celery task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was with the`bind=True` parameter passed into the `@app.task()`. The solution was to remove that parameter:

```
@app.task()
def send_email(...):
    """Sends a single email via Postmark."""
    postmark = PostmarkClient(...)
    response = postmark.emails.send(...)
    log.info('Postmark API send_email response %s', response)
```

Alternatively, I could have added the `self` parameter to the `send_email` method:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def send_email(self, ...):
    """Sends a single email via Postmark."""
    postmark = PostmarkClient(...)
    response = postmark.emails.send(...)
    log.info('Postmark API send_email response %s', response)
```

As the `bind` parameter, binds the method to the App instance.